# How to order in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a section to show users in a library.
This works with AngularJS. You can order clicking in the list headers.

I need to change the default order and I have changed the `action.class.php` query adding an `ORDER BY ID`
This doesn't work, the query results are Ok, but in the template are not ok.

I think the problem is this line:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data| filter:Buscar:true | filtroNombreNormalizado:nombreFiltro | filtroCodLector:codLector | intervaloFechasAlta:fechaAlta.inicio:fechaAlta.fin | intervaloFechasValidez:fechaValidez.inicio:fechaValidez.fin | mostrarSancionados:tipoSancion | orderBy:sort:reverse | limitTo: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize - filtrados.length | limitTo: pageSize">
```

But I don't know how to fix it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

just use orderby filter property inside pass your id

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data| orderBy:data.id>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: is possible order by reverse id?

Comment: yes it is possible to add isreverse keyword in orderby filter

<tr ng-repeat="item in data| orderBy:'-id'>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

To order by reverse id , you can pass true or false for reversing

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data| orderBy:data.id:true>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
</tr>
```

It is mentions in [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

> {{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse : comparator}}

Comment: It doesn´t work. I have used with true or false, and there is no change. I have been using the rest of the line, I mean "item in data| orderBy:data.id:true | filter:Buscar:true | ......"

Comment: User ordey in last , filter must come first

Answer (score 0):

You can use orderby for ng-repeat :

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data| orderBy:data.id">
    <td>{{item}}</td>
</tr>
```

And for reverse, I would suggest using a custom filter such as this:

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.slice().reverse();
  };
});
```

Which can then be used like:

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in friends | reverse">{{friend.name}}</div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/REU7mTsfG5HISCnLKEr8?p=preview)

Comment: Is ignoring the "orderBy:data.id:true" or "orderBy:data.id:false"

Comment: I don't think it should matter

Answer (score 0):

No way, I have tried:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data| filter:Buscar:true | filtroNombreNormalizado:nombreFiltro | filtroCodLector:codLector | intervaloFechasAlta:fechaAlta.inicio:fechaAlta.fin | intervaloFechasValidez:fechaValidez.inicio:fechaValidez.fin | mostrarSancionados:tipoSancion | orderBy:sort:reverse | limitTo: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize - filtrados.length | limitTo: pageSize | orderBy:data.id:false">
```

or

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data| filter:Buscar:true | filtroNombreNormalizado:nombreFiltro | filtroCodLector:codLector | intervaloFechasAlta:fechaAlta.inicio:fechaAlta.fin | intervaloFechasValidez:fechaValidez.inicio:fechaValidez.fin | mostrarSancionados:tipoSancion | orderBy:sort:reverse | limitTo: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize - filtrados.length | limitTo: pageSize | orderBy:data.id:true">
```

or

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data| filter:Buscar:true | filtroNombreNormalizado:nombreFiltro | filtroCodLector:codLector | intervaloFechasAlta:fechaAlta.inicio:fechaAlta.fin | intervaloFechasValidez:fechaValidez.inicio:fechaValidez.fin | mostrarSancionados:tipoSancion | orderBy:sort:reverse | orderBy:data.id:false | limitTo: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize - filtrados.length | limitTo: pageSize">
```

And more combinations

Maybe is this the problem?

```
"| orderBy:sort:reverse | orderBy:data.id:false |"
```

Comment: May be you could create a demo for this?

Comment: I don´t know how to create that :(

Comment: Go to this link : "https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview"  ,  Sign in with github  Create a demo app by adding files.